# Validating with Identical using value from another subform

Tags: validation, zend-form, subform

I've separated a long one page form into subforms anticipating it will be split into a multipage form later in the project lifecycle.  I'm having trouble with the token var in the Identical validator below.

From the Application_Form object:

```
$authorizedIndividual = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
// .. authorizedName text element setup here

$termsAgree = new Zend_Form_SubForm();

// Add termsAgree
$termsAgree->addElement('text', 'termsAgree', array(
    'label'         => 'By typing your name in the preceding field, you, as the authorized individual agree to etc. etc. etc.',
    'class'         => 'termsAgree',
    'required'      => true,
    'filters'       => array('StringTrim'),
    'validators'    => array(
        array('validator' => 'Identical', true, $authorizedIndividual->authorizedName )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `Zend_Validate_Identical` only works with string tokens. The value is retrieved from the context (isValid data) via this token.

The easiest solution to your problem is to define the token within the isValid method and use the `authorizedName` value instead.